# what is the python syntax for checking two lists (how to use the OR logic expression)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am attempting to check a dictionary for existence of an item  (both keys and values) is this syntax correct?

```
  if item in companies.keys() or companies.values()
       append item
```

or is it

```
 if item in (companies.keys() or companies.values())
       append item
```

or something else?

Comment: Where have you seen code like these two examples?  What makes you think the `or` operator works this way?

Comment: If you're searching through values of a dict you're probably using the wrong data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about trying it like this?

```
if (item in companies.keys()) or (item in companies.values()):
    append item
```

I think parentheses around `(x in y)` are optional as the `or` operator has lower precedence.

**Edit:**

However, there are some inefficiencies with using `item in companies.keys()`, espcially in Python version prior to Python 3, where the `.keys()` method iterates over all keys and creates a list of all the keys.

The same test can be rewritten to use a faster and more idiomatic test such as:

```
if (item in companies) or (item in companies.values()):
    append item
```

Or, without the parentheses (although I find it harder to read):

```
if item in companies or item in companies.values():
    append item
```

Comment: `item in companies.keys()` is almost always a bad idea. `item in companies` should be used.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: it's also almost always a bad idea to search in a dict's values.  There are many problems with OP's code, including the choice of data structure.  I tried to keep the answer focused on the question.

Comment: btw, it seems that the view object (result of `.keys()`) implements an efficient `__contains__()` method on Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you perform check for a large list of items:

```
companies_values = set(companies.values())
# ...
for item in items:
    if item not in companies and item not in companies_values:
       # item is not among keys or values of companies
       # add item
```

Don't use `item in companies.keys()`.

`dict.keys` and `dict.values` create new lists (on Python 2.x) each time you call them. It is `O(N)` operation. To find an item in a list is also `O(N)` operation, where `N` is a number of items in a list. `O(N)` roughly means linear time the larger `N` the longer it takes.

On the other hand `item in some_dict` is a amortized `O(1)` operation (on average constant time whatever the size of dictionary is). The same for `item in some_set`.

Comment: This depends on the Python version.  In recent version, `.keys()` and `.values()` return *views* on the dictionary and producing these views does not require a copy.

Comment: @André Caron: Unless the tag says `python-3.x` the answer talks about Python 2.x. In any case the search is still `O(N)` instead of `O(1)` for a dictionary lookup.

Comment: OP is new to SO and questions are mistagged all the time.  Unless OP states the question explicitly states which version, I would avoid misleading generalizations.